# how do I render an NSObject in local HTML template in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a local html file I would like to use as a template to print some different NSObjects, is there a way to render this without having to do a bunch of stringByReplacingOccuranceOfString methods?

Looking for something I would do in MVC on a web site:

HTML Template:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Manufacturer</h1>
     <p>
     ##Manufacturer.ManufacturerName##
     </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And would call some function passing in the Manufacturer object and get an NSString back of that template with the object property values substituted in place of my placeholder values.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Manufacturer</h1>
 <p>
%@
 </p>
</body>
</html>",  Manufacturer.ManufaacturerName];  
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"some random page"]];  //I'm not entirely sure what the baseURL is used for
```

Comment: problem with that is I have about 100 places to replace data.

Comment: Then have a lot of %@'s or use something other than a web view (maybe a table view?), or make it a web app.

Comment: this is going to be used for printing locally so it can't be web based and can't send a UIView directly to the printer.  And rendering a multi-page view to PDF is a real PITA.

Comment: But it can be web based, you can get the data (a web page) from your server and put it in your own UIWebview (not in Safari), and print it using UIPrintInteractionController by taking the web view's NSURL and sending that to the printer.

Comment: I can't guarantee a connection so it cannot be web based - I already have the web based version working this is in case there is not a connection

Comment: Then you can do it the way I described and convert the string to NSData to send it to the printer.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the always-brilliant Matt Gemmell's [MGTemplateEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/05/20/mgtemplateengine-templates-with-cocoa).

Comment: looks sweet - thank you, but says requires OS X Leopard, I need to do this on an iPhone & iPad

Comment: Try it anyway. It will likely work in iOS with minimal changes (probably no changes).

Comment: I'll give it a shot and let you know - thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/groue/GRMustache is a nice alternative to Matt Gemmel's MGTemplateEngine that works on both iOS and MacOS out of the box, and has copious documentation.

Comment: this is what I finally ended up doing